# Caller not authenticated when attempting access sharepoint list using Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Trying to use Microsoft's Graph beta to access a Sharepoint list via a registered Azure app using a key.  I'm able to successful see/access some lists(looks like only lists created when site was created), but any list I have manually created is missing.

I can do the following get to list most lists in my site:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com,fc016e3c-d8ae-4ee0-a10c-de6d26788b6a,9a4ea7a5-c3c4-44ae-9f80-273bd67431b8\lists
```

but for some reason it's only displaying certain lists and none of the ones I created. However if enter the list's GUID like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com,fc016e3c-d8ae-4ee0-a10c-de6d26788b6a,9a4ea7a5-c3c4-44ae-9f80-273bd67431b8/lists/BEA4B4A9-323F-441A-BA19-806290B27EF6
```

I receive "the caller is not authenticated" message back.   This is message has me thinking it's a permissions issue, however, my list permissions are the same on all lists.  it's as if the graph api can only see lists created by the system and not by end users.

Anybody experiencing this issue?

Comment: Could you share the request-id and date headers for your request? I'll need that information to look this up in our logs and see what's going on.

Comment: { "error": { "code": "unauthenticated", "message": "The caller is not authenticated.", "innerError": { "request-id": "b79ac330-3078-44a4-b652-048aa5542e5d", "date": "2017-05-16T21:55:03" } } }

Comment: figured I'd add, incase it's not obvious, I am switching out my domain for the contoso.sharepoint.com along with my GUIDs

Comment: any luck? getting the same

Comment: No luck yet. I ended up storing info in an excel spreadsheet on somebody's OneDrive and using graph to read the spreadsheet. It's not elegant by any means but does do what I need, which was provide data to  daemon website on a raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue on my end.  The "save item to list" function works for some accounts and not others...  It's extremely weird!  Typical SharePoint, I suppose.

What I've come to realize is that GRAPH will sometimes throw an error when trying to save data to a *date field* and works every time saving data to *text fields*.  If I'm logged in as my main O365 account (with license) I can save to date fields.  If I'm logged in with a basic user that I just created on the domain (no license) I can create items *unless* there's a date field.

If I come up with anything else I'll post it!  Sorry, this is more of a work-around than an answer.  Hopefully it will spark something else.

Thanks